# PUT needs to be rescheduled

Tags: support, status-completed

Us crazy Americans went back on DST a few weeks ago, so now PUT is at the wrong time. And since it's scheduled to end on 2012/03/31, it's time to reschedule it anyway. Can we get the event rescheduled for 19:00-21:00 GMT until 2012/11/01? We could also have another winter PUT scheduled for 20:00-22:00 GMT from 2012/11/07 until 2013/03/07. And if anyone would like to get rid of DST completely, I'd be happy with that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh yes. The UK changes time this weekend too, so it makes sense.

I can't create a recurring summer and winter schedule as there's only two dates, but we should remember to create the winter schedule in October.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I wasn't sure if you could create a second event and schedule it to start in the future.

Comment: @BMitch - I can, but it seems a bit of overkill at the moment.